# Finding a random occurence in a numpy array when more than one choice

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code to achieve the goal of returning a random value from a list of elements that are matching a predicate condition:

```
N=<int>
sampl = np.random.randint(low=0, high=N+1, size=(10,))
xs = np.where(sampl == 1)
ys = np.array([tuple(x) for x in xs], dtype=int)[0]
x = np.random.choice(ys)
```

Ex: If I run the code with `N=2` and I am looking for only `1`s in the array:

```
    sampl = np.random.randint(low=0, high=N+1, size=(10,))

--> sampl = [2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 1]

    xs = np.where(sampl == 1)

--> [2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 1]  # Positions 1, 5, 9 are of interest. 
       ^       ^       ^ 

    ys = np.array([tuple(x) for x in xs], dtype=int)[0]

--> ys = [1 5 9] # Put them in an array. 

    x = np.random.choice(ys)

--> x = 9 # Pick a random one and return it
```

It works but it's not concise and I ran into a few issues trying to make it more elegant.

- `numpy.where()` returns a tuple when passing nothing else but a condition. I tried passing `x=sampl` but the runtime complains saying that the function doesn't take params (it does when I inspect the code).
- Again, making a numpy array from a tuple forces me to return the first element. That's error-prone when testing for edge-cases (such as no value found by predicate.)

Do you have any suggestions to improve this code? I want to stick to numpy/pandas as the arrays will become very big.

Comment: By edge cases, you mean the case where there is no element?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. From what you are saying it seems to me you may be looking for something like `np.random.choice(x[cond(x)])` where `cond(x)` is something that returns a boolean mask like for example`x>=2` .

Comment: @PaulPanzer I like your example, but how to keep it to one liner? `lambda`?

Comment: You can literally write `np.random.choice(x[x>=2])`.

Comment: Where does the `x>=2` comes from?

Comment: It is just an example. Another example: you could for `np.where(sampl == 1)` write `(np.arange(sampl.size)[sampl == 1],)` (don't actually do it, it is just to illustrate how boolean indexing works)

Comment: I settled with `numpy.where()` as there is not option to return the current index it's in when the predicate succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most elegant way I could think of is to randomly shuffle your array, and then pull off the first occurrence. That should be pretty concise.

So something like:

```
np.random.shuffle(sampl)
x = np.ravel(np.where(sampl==1))[0]
```

or, like you suggested, without shuffling, that would look something like

```
x = np.random.choice(np.ravel(np.where(sampl==1)))
```

On second thought, I guess the `choice` method will be infinitely faster than shuffling.

The next issue is the edge cases. How to handle this depends on what you expect the default behavior to be. If you expect that in most cases the condition will turn up at least one hit, then you should handle the case when there is not a hit with an exception:

```
try: 
   x = np.random.choice(np.ravel(np.where(sampl==1)))
except: 
   # TODO
   pass
```

I would highly suggest doing this unless you rarely find a hit. But don't take my word for it... time it yourself.

The other option would be to put in a condition that explicitly checks that

```
np.size( np.where(sampl==1) ) > 0
```

before continuing. However, I would guess that that approach is slower than the `try...except`approach.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. Unfortunately, I can't shuffle the original array as it's also used in parallel with other arrays (think samples for test, valid and train in ML.) I suppose I could do a shuffle on a copy but as I wrote, the data is big and would be causing memory issues. I will look into `numpy.ravel()` as it seems to be a nice way to avoid the `[0]` postfix. However I am still not quite sure how to force `numpy.where()` not to return a tuple but a `numpy.array()`. The call with `x=...` should work, right?

Comment: Shuffling is a bad idea. Ignore that tidbit. Use the random choice